# Trying to send a message to Multiple Discord channels

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord.js

I have made a Discord bot with Discord.js and MongoDB for my discord servers.

So in my MongoDB, I have the variable for a channel ID, which is a different channel in each of my 3 discords. With the code below, when I run the command, the message only get sent to the first discord channel in the database. Any idea's on what i'm doing wrong?

````
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, settings, guild, channels) => {
   if (message.channel.id === '123456789') {
    bot.guilds.forEach(guild => {
   const sayMessage = args.join(" ");

let sicon = message.guild.iconURL;
let serverembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setTitle("**Announcement**")
.setFooter("from SpikyZA", sicon)
.setTimestamp()
.setColor("#5500FF")
.addField("Message", `${sayMessage}`);

//let testchannel = guild.channels.find(c => c.id === `${settings.notify}`);
bot.channels.get(`${settings.notify}`).send(serverembed);
   });
}
};

module.exports.help = {
  name:"test",
  aliases: ["test"]
};```
````

Comment: The ids of channels of each server are different, you can get the default channel of 3 guilds and send the message there, either you can make an array of channels and correspond them to guilds and send for each.

Comment: Ah ok. I thought I could use the individual channel ID's being pulled from the database. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for a simple way to do it, try looping through the amount of items in the database, like this:

```js
for(n = 0; n <= channelDB.length; n++){
  let ch = bot.channels.get(channelDB.channels[n].id);
  ch.send(embed);
}
```

or whatever similar code works with `MongoDB` ‍♂️